# A little animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

How can I make or where can I find a script for the effect from the header of this page http://www.prorider.ro/ ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Single Parallax* or *Mouse Parallax* is what you're looking for.

Maybe one of the following tutorials may help you; a simple Google search could have taken you to them.

**On SO**

- [Move the background image on mouse over (Single Parallax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424317/move-the-background-image-on-mouse-over-single-parallax)
- [Smoothing movement effect that follows mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947477/smoothing-movement-effect-that-follows-mouse-position)

**External references**

- [Create an Interactive Moving Background or Object that Reacts to Viewer’s Cursor](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2014/04/09/create-an-interactive-moving-backgroundobject-that-reacts-to-viewers-cursor/)
- [jQuery Parallax Tutorial – Animated Header Background](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-parallax-tutorial/)
- [Move background image with mouse follow](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/6981-move-background-image-with-mouse-follow/)
- [Interactive Mouse Hover Parallax Effect with jQuery - Mouse Parallax](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Interactive-Mouse-Hover-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-Mouse-Parallax.html)

and so on...

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.